# Vim execute :e ++ff=dos from vimrc

Tags: vim, file-format

Occasionally I have to work with mixed Unix/DOS files in Vim. That file will show `^M` on the end on most of the lines.  I can't convert the whole file to just Unix format.

Fix for that is `:e ++ff=dos`

I have tried to incorporate that in my vimrc at least as a shorcut (if not autocmd) but without success.

`ga` for `^M` will show:

```
<^M>  13,  Hex 0d,  Octal 15
```

This won't work from vimrc:

```
function! Fix_dos()
    execute "normal :e ++ff=dos<cr>"
endfunction
```

I have tried something with conceal feature, but that won't conceal all `^M` chars.

```
:set conceallevel=2
:syntax match Todo /\r/ conceal
```

Also, is there a way to detect if file will show `^M` chars?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do `:e +ff=dos`, you convert the file to DOS format; i.e. after writing, *all* line endings will be converted to CR-LF. You've mentioned that you cannot *convert to the whole file to Unix format*, but if converting to DOS is okay, then this is the solution.

For your function, you don't need to go through `:normal`, as the `:e` command is an Ex command, and those can be directly used in a function. You only need `:normal` for normal-mode commands like `dd`. Therefore, you can rewrite:

```
function! Fix_dos()
    " This would be the correct syntax, but no need for :normal:
    "execute "normal :e ++ff=dos\<cr>"
    " Also, no need for execute:
    "execute "e ++ff=dos"
    edit ++ff=dos
endfunction
```

In fact, I would define:

```
:command! FixDos edit ++ff=dos
```

---

If you cannot covert the entire file, you'll have to live with the `^M`; best you can do is trying to hide them, as you've tried with concealing. This variant might catch *more* instances of `^M` by also appying inside other syntax groups:

```
:syntax match Todo /\r/ conceal containedin=ALL
```

Answer (score 0):

Opening a buffer in DOS fileformat does not *convert* the file to UNIX format. It is only sufficient if you wish to edit the buffer as DOS, and write it as DOS too. Hiding ^M also doesn't convert - your questions gives me the impression you think it does.

If you want to convert to LF-line-endings-only,

1. Remove all ^M characters: `:%s/<C-V><cr>//ge<cr>`. You can incorporate that in a function or autocommand.
2. Mark the buffer to use only LF line endings: `:setlocal ff=unix`

Comment: I prefer to convert DOS to UNIX with two clear steps: (1) `:e ++ff=dos <filename>` and then (2) `:w ++ff=unix`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid having to press a key before your file opens:

> "Press ENTER or type command to continue"

Run the command silently, like this:

```
com! SetFileFormatDos edit ++ff=dos
:silent SetFileFormatDos
```

Also, note the uppercase "S" from SetFileFormatDos.